# Pandas groupby inherits groups from parent dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to group by a categorical variable `installation_id`. For some reason groupby seems to include groups that aren't in the dataframe itself. For example:

```
df.groupby('installation_id').size() # Length of each group

installation_id
0001e90f     0
000447c4     0
0006a69f    16
0006c192     7
0009a5a9     0
            ..
```

I would not expect any of the groups to have 0 rows.

This dataframe was made as a subset of a larger dataframe, so I assume it is inheriting the groups from the larger dataframe? How do I prevent this so I get the expected result?

I have tried `df = df.copy()` before grouping and this makes no difference.

Thanks for any help, I am relatively new to this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a *FEATURE* of grouping by Categorical data.

Instead use:

```
df.groupby(df['installation_id'].to_numpy()).size()
```

OR MUCH MORE SIMPLY from ALollz
(will delete if ALollz posts answer)

```
df.groupby('installation_id', observed=True).size()
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed